# Various Errors, depending on format - RunTime "438", "91", "13"

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to copy multiple columns from one `workbook` into another based on the values in a third column. I've attempted multiple formats for this, declaring the Object as `range`, or `variant`, setting the selected range as `.value` or `.select`.  All in all, this has resulted in Runtime Errors 438, 424, 91, and 13.

This most recent iteration is producing 'Runtime error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method`.

```
Sub Fetch()
    Dim Group As String
    Dim gPath As String
    Dim BUname As String
    Dim PMAname As String
    Dim Backup As Workbook
    Dim PMA As Workbook
    Dim Fetch As Workbook, Home As Worksheet

    Set Fetch = ThisWorkbook
    Set Home = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home")
    Group = Range("B2").Value
    mola = Range("B1").Value
    maybe = Format(mola, "mm")
    real = Format(mola, "yy")
    nope = Format(mola, "yyyy")
    ShtNm = Format(mola, "mm.yy")
    gPath = "U:\BILLREC\M & R EG Billing\Analysts\My Name\" & Group & "\M2M\Original Backup" & "\" & nope & "\"
    BUname = gPath & maybe & "." & real & " " & "Original Backup" & ".xlsx"
    PMAname = gPath & maybe & "." & real & " " & "PMA" & ".xlsx"

    'Opens Backup File and determines current premium
    Set Backup = Workbooks.Open(BUname)

        Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Copy
        Home.Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("N2"), Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Copy
        Home.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        If Application.CountIf(Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Values, "<>0") < 0 Then 'Runtime 438 occurs here.
            Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BX2"), Range("BX2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            Home.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BY2"), Range("BY2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            Home.Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("CA2"), Range("CA2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            Home.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("CB2"), Range("CB2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            Home.Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If

    Set PMA = Workbooks.Open(PMAname)
End Sub
```

Another variation I've attempted is naming the actual range... again, this results in a 438:

```
Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("N2"), Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Copy
Home.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Values 'Error Occurs here now.

If Application.CountIf(TotPrm, "<>0") < 0 Then
    Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BX2"), Range("BX2").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Home.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BY2"), Range("BY2").End(xlDown)).Copy
    Home.Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else
```

I've attempted to declare `TotPrm` as both a `Range`, and a `Variant` with the same 438 via:

```
Dim TotPrm As Range
```

and

```
Dim TotPrm As Variant
```

With the same 438 occurring at the same point.

Changing `.Values` to `.Value` resulted in a Runtime 424 Object Required:

```
Set TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Value 'This line is the bane of my existence
```

My dataset that this is being run against is:

```
BW       BX      BY      BZ       CA      CB
TotPrmA  CurA    RetroA  TotPrmB  CurB    RetroB
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $42.55   $42.55  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $39.72   $39.72  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $39.72   $39.72  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $41.14   $41.14  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $41.14   $41.14  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $41.14   $41.14  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $82.28   $82.28  $0.00 
$0.00    $0.00   $0.00   $39.72   $39.72  $0.00
```

This is an array of `Total Premiums`, `Current Premiums`, `Retroactive Adjustments` that are repeated.  As you can see by the `If...Else` function that immediately follows my troublesome devil, it's looking for a value other than zero in the first `Total Premiums` column, and determining which columns to copy over based on the results. With `TotPrm` declared as `Variant` and defined as `Range.Value` it produces the `Runtime Error 13: Type Mismatch` at the same line.

Last but not least, the Runtime 91:

```
Dim TotPrm As Range
TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Value
```

I'm at my wits' end.  Any help would be *vastly* appreciated!

Comment: What exactly _is_ your `ShtNm`? It looks like it's supposed to be calling an index of your worksheets (`i.e., 1, 2, ...`) but you are formatting a value to "MM.YY" and calling that as your worksheet index? Or is that the actual sheet name itself?

Comment: `Set TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Value` the problem here is the `.Value`. `.Value` is not an *object*, and therefore can't be assigned using the `Set` keyword. If you need an object, get rid of `.Value`. If you need a value, get rid of `.Set`.

Comment: `.Values` is not a property of range object, it's `.Value`.

Comment: `TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Value` fails because you''ve defined `TotPrem` as an object (`Range`) but you're attempting to assign to it some other data type (the `range.Value` is not a `Range` (and even if it were, you'd need to use `Set` keyord), but a string,numeric/etc.) It seems like you do not understand object types & assignment statements for VBA?

Comment: @Busse, The sheetname is variable based on the month/year the report is generated for. I.e. Report is for July 2017, the wb name is "07.17 Original Backup" and the specific Sheet is "07.17".

@DavidZemens You're right, I'm a complete VBA newb, learning as I go.  I've tried multiple variants on the theme - Assigning it as an object with `Range` and `.Set` or without... I've tried to re-produce all variations I've tried here, but simply couldn't remember them all. Mostly, this is representative of all, however.

Comment: @DavidZemens, your first comment indicates that I should simply drop the `.Value` from `TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Select`, if I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: Don't use `Select`. And if `TotPrm` is an object you'll need to use `Set` to assign to it. Also, ensure you've scoped ranges to the correct worksheet, per the answer given below, otherwise you may get 1004 error.

Comment: I did get the 1004 error, but that was because I had not yet corrected all my sheet-names to my standardized format.  Your solution worked, regarding `Set TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown))` with `Dim TotPrm As Range`.  You've spared my sanity.  If you could apply that as an answer, so I can set this as "Answered," I would appreciate it.  Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dim TotPrm As Range` expects a `Range` object when assigned, and since it's an object, must use the `Set` keyword:

```
Set TotPrm = <expression that evaluates to an instance of a Range object>
```

So when you do this, you're missing the `Set` keyword for starters, also the `Select` method actually returns a `Boolean` (True/False) value, not the range itself.

```
TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Select
```

Likewise, this fails because you've defined `TotPrem` as an object (`Range`) but you're attempting to assign to it some other data type -- the `range.Value` is not a `Range` (and even if it were, you'd need to use `Set` keyord as above) -- but a string,numeric/etc.

```
TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown)).Value`
```

Remove the `Select` (or `.Value`, etc.) and use `Set`:

```
Set TotPrm = Backup.Sheets(ShtNm).Range(Range("BW2"), Range("BW2").End(xlDown))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to fully qualify all range references (see the dots below) otherwise they may refer to different sheets which will cause an error. Eg

```
With Backup.Sheets(ShtNm)
  .Range(.Range("N2"), .Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With
```

Second, what is the `Values` property? Your final formulation looks to me ok as long as you declare `TotPrm` as Variant.

Comment: That line already works correctly.  That section opens a variable path/wb name, and copy/pastes two specific columns into the one I am working in. It operates correctly w/o fail.  It's the next step where the errors occur, when I'm attempting to check a column for the existence of any value other than 0, then copy/paste columns based on that result.

Comment: That's not what you said above. Perhaps specify exactly which line(s) is erroring. I am showing you good practice because your current code could cause errors in future even if it doesn't now.

Comment: I will keep the `With...End With` coding in mind for the next time I go into doing something beyond my scope.  Thank you for this.  However I pinpointed w/in the code the lines that were causing issues with commentary.